# Is it possible to disable selection on p:selectManyMenu in primefaces when a certain item is selected?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `p:selectManyMenu` which has a list of countries as items. I can select multiple items from here. I also have an option '**All Countries**' which implies that all countries are selected. When I select the item 'All Countries' it should block further selection. Here is my code

```html
<p:selectManyMenu id="country" value="#{countryBean.selCountry}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{countryBean.countryList}" var="ctry" 
                    itemValue="#{ctry.countryName}" itemLabel="#{ctry.countryName}"/>
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

Comment: Did you want to disable the all list or all list except "all countries" ??!

Comment: You'll need to add a boolean flag on the country entity, and bind that to the `itemDisabled` attribute on the `f:selectItems`. Then just ajax-update the menu items